# Marketing Cloud Mobile push message creates new Inbox in Mobile App

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush

When we trigger a message to download to the mobile app’s inbox on users’ mobile devices using Mobile Push from Marketing Cloud the messages are landing in a New Inbox in the mobile app.

Can we link the messages to appear in the existing Inbox of the mobile app instead of Salesforce creating a new Inbox?  Now the app has 2 Inboxes.

I believe it is possible to make the messages land in existing Inbox but I can't find the SDK documentation that explains this.  Any pointers?

Comment: Did you try to use getMessages() method in your existing inbox ? http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/javadocs/6.0/reference/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/messages/inbox/InboxMessageManager.html

Comment: iOS or Android?  What version(s) of the SDK?  For Android, we do not "create" an Inbox as anything with regards to the view and messaging handling is up to your application.  iOS provides a barebones implementation of the view/view controller, but yeah, what @zeljazouli said.